# Which version SASS bootstrap is better?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I found two versions of sass based bootstrap and I don't know which better to use for a non rails application.
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass
https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap#readme

And my second question how their compatibility with third part bootstrap addons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap for a while and I haven't experienced any issue. This repo support bower, author is very active. I recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

And now, if you go to the page mentioned in the answer, you can see the following message:

> ATTENTION: This project has reached it's end of life. There is a new
>   official port of Bootstrap to Sass. Please use this in all future
>   projects.

And the link is pointing to the https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass again.